# capturing a java.xml.ws (apache CXF) request using fiddler (unable to find valid certification path to requested target)

Tags: java, cxf, jax-ws, fiddler

I am using fiddler running on the default port (8866) I have trusted the fake certificate and am capturing requests.

I have set the necessary proxy parameters in my spring boot application.

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "localhost");
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "localhost");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8866");
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "8866");
System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");
```

When the request is made, I get the `CONNECT` captured by fiddler, and then this exception in java.

> PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

**How do I bypass or turn off this validation temporarily to capture the request?**

Comment: Java does not make use of the Windows certificate store. Therefore you manually have add the Fiddler root CA certificate to the Java trust store or create a new trust store with the Fiddler root CA cert in it and specify that trust store at start-up.

Comment: you can post that as the answer @Robert and I will tick it.